# request for member xxxx in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, pass-by-reference

I am trying to write a function to add insert a node to a linked list. The function arguments are the pointer to the pointer to the node where the element should be inserted and the element. I get the error
request for member ‘data’ in something not a structure or union
request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union

Where next and data are the two fields in the linked list

```
void INSERT(int element, struct Node** position)
{
    //If inserting at front
    if( *position==NULL){

            *position -> data = element;
            *position -> next = NULL;
            return;
    }

    //the node to be inserted is named temp
    struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));


    //create cell
    temp -> data = element;
    temp -> next = *position->next;

    *position-> next = temp;


}
```

The definition of the struct node is

```
 struct Node
 {
    int data;//payload
    struct Node* next;
 };
```

The main function calls INSERT

```
int main()
{
    struct Node *head =(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head -> data =5;
    head -> next  = NULL;

    INSERT(2,&head);
    INSERT(3,&head);



   PRINTLIST(&head);
    return 0;
 }
```

PRINTLIST just prints the list. It works fine

Comment: Advice: add the definition of `struct Node` to this post, and you will soon get an answer...

Comment: the  definition of struct Node is ... ?

Comment: If `*position == NULL` you need to allocate it first

Comment: I just added the definition of the Node

Comment: and `*position->next;` --> `(*position)->next;`

Comment: are these in the same file (ie: struct Node definition, main, INSERT)?

Comment: Sorry I changed the argument for INSERT back to Node**. I created a .h file with the prototypes and a separate c file for the INSERT and PRINTLIST  functions

Comment: No. The Node definition is in the header file. The INSERT and printlist functions are in the corresponding .c file

Comment: I got it working guys. The problem seems that when I'm using *position, the compiler didn't understand it was a node. But when I used (*position) it did. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Priorities of the binding of the operator is different. `*position->next` meant `*(position->next)`.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably like this

```
void INSERT(int element, struct Node **position){
    struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp -> data = element;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    if( *position==NULL){
        *position = temp;
        return;
    }
    temp->next = (*position)->next;
    (*position)->next = temp;
}
//result : //5 -> 3 -> 2 : is inserted next to the head
```